# Adding geoJSON feature attributes to mapbox popup

Tags: javascript, gis, leaflet, mapbox, geojson

I am looking to add a popup with geoJSON attributes to each book store marker on my map. I have used "layer.feature.properties.name" within the marker.bindpopup method, but am getting a return of "undefined".

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'jk.eyJ1IjsdkjfhskjdfhksdskdjflWNCJ9.Ov2O5PtskdljfsdR0lq3Q';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'example.kks3kec4')
    .setView([38.633, -90.319],12);

//add cafe, books store, and university geoJSON layers with styling
var bookStore = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
    .loadURL('book_store84.geojson')
    //wait for the layer to be "on", or "loaded", to use a function that will setIcon with an L.icon object
    .on('ready', function(layer) {
        this.eachLayer(function(marker) {
            marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                'marker-color': '#BA1A1A',
                'marker-symbol': "library",
                'description': "book store"
            }));
            //when layer.feature is within the popup, it returns "undefined"
            marker.bindPopup("<p>" + layer.feature.properties.name + "</p>");
        });
    })
    .addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `layer` variable:

```
marker.bindPopup("<p>" + layer.feature.properties.name + "</p>");
```

The `layer` variable does not contain the `feature` object. You are looping over the contained layers assigning them to the `marker` variable, those have the `feature` object, so you should that:

```
marker.bindPopup("<p>" + marker.feature.properties.name + "</p>");
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This is exactly what I needed and was such a simple fix. Wish I would have asked earlier.